# QTableWidget - setCellWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, custom-widgets

I try to insert a custom widget into a `QTableWidget` using the `setCellWidget` function

```
void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )
```

My problem is now, that the paint method of the custom widget isn't called. Anyone knows why?

Best regards

Comment: Is it called, when you add you widget just to form (QWidget)?

Comment: I just saw that the paint function is called indeed. But i can't paint. It says: "paint returned engine = 0". Also a label, which is placed inside the custom widget, is not there.

Comment: First check that you widget work properly outside `QTableWidget`. You cannot be sure that your problem is connected with `QTableWidget` until you check whether your widget work outside it.

Comment: It's working properly outside QTableWidget. I made some more tests. My custom widgets is made out of several outer custom widgets. The paint method of the first widget, which holds all the others, is called. But the paint methods of the other custom widgets are not called. Outside QTabelWidget everythings works fine.

Comment: Ok i can paint lines with QPainter. But the background color of the custom widget is ignored.

Comment: How did you set the background color (stylesheet, palette...) ? Does the custom widget inherit **directly** from QWidget ?

Comment: Did you try setAutofillBackground(true) on your widget? By default, widgets do not fill the background automatically unless this option is set.

Comment: Provide an example of the problem that we can reproduce it.